# Pass array to JSON object along with other variables to be used in ajax

Tags: c#, arrays, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

It's my first time to pass an array to ajax using JSON object. As you can see with my code, I'm not sure how to properly pass an array to a JSON object to be read by ajax. When it got passed to the Controller, the `items` variable in the parameter is empty.

View Javasript

```
var itemprice = [];
//Populate itemprice. This will be used to check if the newly added item is already existing
$('#tblItem tbody tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function () {
    itemprice.push($(this).text());
});

var json = {
    item: $('#item').val(),
    itemtypeid: $('#itemtype option:selected').val(),
    itempromocount: $('#tblItem tbody tr #tditem_promo').length,
    items: itemprice //I'm not sure how to pass an array to Controller
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/Items/CheckItems',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Error! " + xhr.status);
    }
});
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult CheckItems(string itemtypeid, int itempromocount, string items)
{
    //itemtypeid and itempromocount has value but items don't have
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller `items` is a list of string :

```
public JsonResult CheckItems(string itemtypeid, int itempromocount, List<string> items)
{
    //itemtypeid and itempromocount has value but items don't have
}
```

Comment: Oh God why! I feel so stupid haha. Thanks for pointing that out, man! I thought it was how I pass the array to the JSON object